# How can i bind an extra click event to a hyperlink using jQuery 1.4?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to loop trough all email-links on a webpage. Then add GA tracking to each one of them. So below i have just been testing to get the binding to work, but that fails for some reason and tried to open the email client when i view the page.

```
var emails = $('a[href^="mailto:"]');
for (var i = 0; i < emails.length; i++){
    var email = emails[i];
    email.click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('test');
        //_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Emails', $(this).pathname]);
    });
}
```

Right now i want the popup to appear when i click the link, but it's not working.

Comment: Array items in emails are not jQuery objects. They are DOM elements. So they don't have the click property.

Comment: Hans is correct, you would need to wrap the email like this: `$(email).click(...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be more direct:

```
  $('a[href^="mailto:"]').click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       alert('test');
  })
```

jQuery masquerades as an array of the elements its selector selects. By applying a handler to the jQuery object in this fashion, it actually attaches the handler to all elements that satisfy the selection criteria.

Comment: How would i get the path back inside the function? I want to get the email from the mailto:link. e in this case is just the event but not the actual link itself?

Comment: You would use the `this` keyword, which is pretty darned mysterious until you learn how to use it. http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/this-keyword/ http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/fully-understanding-the-this-keyword/  At any rate, in your click handler, `this` will refer to the DOM object in question, but if you need to jQueryify it, you can wrap it like so: `$(this)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$.each` something like this.

```
$( 'a[href^="mailto:"]' ).each(function() {
    $( this ).click(function(){
       e.preventDefault();
       alert('test');
       //_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Emails', $(this).pathname]);
    });
});
```